# Reading the content of file section wise in java

Tags: java, windows

I want to read the content of any files like doc, pdf, ppt etc section or paragraph wise in java, because i want to retrieve a particular section of a file (if have) instead of retrieving the content of whole file.. Please can anyone tell me, How can i read the content of any file either section or paragraph wise………..

Thanks

Comment: Each one of the file formats you mention (doc, pdf, etc) have entirely file formats.  You would have to find or write a parser/processor for each file format you intend to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends entirely on the format of the file in question. For example, when you have a `.docx` file, you can employ some XML parser and then iterate through the result or use XPath to find all paragraphs, sections or whatever you wish to extract.

For other file formats you will have to find a different approach. There is no single way to extract a specific part of any file, as different file types have different ways of storing data. Most likely, you will have to collect a bunch of libraries, one for each file type.

Comment: Thank Swapnil and Forsythe........I have tried in java, and able to extract whole contents at a time, but i want to retrieve section wise content instead of whole. How to write a parser for a file. Is it possible to write automatic parser, which can parse any file in any format.